# Why do i see traffic on the Compute Engine API?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-api

I am using Google cloud to run some services. speifically, I have code running in firebase, as well as Cloud Run and Cloud SQL.

For some reason, however, I am seeing constant traffic to a compute engine API, which I have no idea why? I don't have any VM's setup (outside of what Cloud SQL is running), but I'm assuming that's a separate service.

Why would I be seeing this traffic against this API? I could "disable" it, but the warning says any resources created with it could soon be deleted and I don't want to bring down my Cloud SQL or Cloud Run instances. There's nothing I can taht would generate 418,000+ requests this month....unless this is just internal Google stuff to support my cloud SQL and Cloud run instances?

Any ideas what this could be? Should it be safe to disable this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will see traffic on the Compute Engine API because you are actually using the service.

CE API is not just related for GCE instances, it handles much more of that, for example: Disk, Firewall, Snapshots etc.

You can find more information about the CE API [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1)

So I recommend not disable the CE API because it can cause errors and other problems.